# Apply actions over selected elements in a list in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which has 4 elements, and I want to loop over the last 2. So I tried this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
arg1=$1
arg2=$2
arg3=$3
arg4=$4
list_total=( "$3 $4" )

for my_element in "${list_total}"; do
    echo "$my_element"
    echo "Wow"
done
```

When running it with `sh myscript.sh Joe Jack Jim Jess` the output is:

```
Jim Jess
Wow
```

But it's not what I intended with the script. I want to output:

```
Jim
Wow
Jess
Wow
```

Please, could you point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Actually here `"$3 $4"` you concatenate two elements. That's you iterate over one -element array and got printed `Jim Jess`

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create the `list_total` array with separate elements instead of a single string. To do this, change the line `list_total=( "$3 $4" )` to `list_total=( "$3" "$4" )`. Something like:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
arg1=$1
arg2=$2
arg3=$3
arg4=$4
list_total=( "$3" "$4" ) # <--- Here

for my_element in "${list_total[@]}"; do
    echo "$my_element"
    echo "Wow"
done
```

**Alternative to this incase if you're looking:**

*[Shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)*

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Directly access the script's arguments
for ((i = 3; i <= 4; i++)); do
  my_element="${!i}"
  echo "$my_element"
  echo "Wow"
done
```

***[SAMPLE DEMO](https://replit.com/@msankrit/ComposedAgreeableConsultant)***

Comment: Thanks @mandy8055, I see that I had to change not only the `list_total=( "$3 $4" )`, but also there is a `"${list_total[@]}"` required

Answer (score 1):

Another version using array splice:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
list_total=$@
for my_element in ${list_total[@]:3:4}; do
    echo "$my_element"
    echo "Wow"
done
```

Comment: Thanks @Bondarenko, so lists in bash are indexed starting in 1? Every day I learn something new!

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies two serious errors in the code.  `list_total` is a string, not an array.  `${list_total[@]:3:4}` (surprisingly) is a string slice, not an array slice.  Try running the code with the single argument `0123456` to see what is going on.

Comment: @Alexis, the list of command line arguments is indexed from 1 (`$1`, `$2`, ...).  Array elements are indexed from 0 (`${arr[0]}`, `${arr[1]}`, ...).